# Backend bucket versioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

We have bucket with some files behind the CDN, along with signed URLs. We are using query string with version to update content [according to the best practices](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/best-practices#use_versioned_urls_to_update_content), e.g. file.ext?v=100.

Everthing worked well until the recent time. The documentation now states that backend buckets do not process query strings. However previously we didn’t meet such restriction, so it seems to be a recent change.

Are there any workarounds to achieve near real-time updates? We cannot get rid of CDN because of latency, and cannot change file names as it would require to many code changes. Invalidation is not an option too.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the official documentation states that:

> For backend buckets, the cache key consists of the URI without the query string. [1](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cache-keys)

Seems like the reason for the change is that the old behavior resulted in lost caching opportunities, higher costs and higher latency. The only recommended workaround for now is to create the new objects by incorporating the version into the object's name or using invalidation, which are not valid options for your case.

But it should not matter that the bucket is not evaluating the query string since the CDN should still do that. In fact I could reproduce this same scenario and currently is still possible to use a query string as cache buster.

---